# How to install drivers to recognize my Intel HD 3000 graphics card? (on Ubuntu 14.04LTS)

Tags: drivers, graphics, 14.04, intel-graphics, gpu

I have tried installing the drivers from the offcial linux graphics drivers at the intel page (it was called something like Intel HD Graphics Installer 1.03) but apparently it only works for Ubuntu 13 or less. So my question is, is there other ways of making my pc use this GPU or do I just wait for intel to release a new installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 already comes with the latest graphics stack, so you don't need the installer.
You're up to date :)

Comment: But then why go to Details in settings it says Graphisc Intel Sandybridge mobile instead of Intel HD 3000? Is it just not showing or is it not using my GPU?

Comment: @user277449 because `Intel Sandybridge Mobile` is the codename for `Intel HD 3000`

Comment: Oh... that explains it all. I am new to Ubuntu and I just get confused sometimes. Thank you

Comment: see this: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics#Sandy_Bridge). Glad to help you! :)

Comment: I think Intel Sandybridge Mobile is a placeholder when it cannot identify the gpu exactly